# Gradle Jacoco - coverage reports includes classes excluded in configuration

Tags: gradle, jacoco

I added to a project a set of sources that don't have tests and I don't want them spoil my test coverage statistics. I configured Jacoco in the next way :

```
test {
    jacoco{
        excludes = ['org/bla/**']
        includes = ['com/bla/**']
        append = false
    }
}

jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports after running tests."
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        html.enabled true
    }
    classDirectories = fileTree(dir: 'build/classes/main', include: 'com/bla/**')
    sourceDirectories = fileTree(dir: 'scr/main/java', include: 'com/bla/**')
}
```

But anyway, when generating the report, Jacoco also includes classes from **org.bla**

Can someone help me ?

**EDIT**

After some debugging, it appears that all default outputs are added to `org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport#classDirectories` in a private method `org.gradle.testing.jacoco.plugins.JacocoPlugin#addDefaultReportTasks`

That's visible when using such code :

```
jacocoTestReport {
    classDirectories = files('build/classes/main/com/bla')
    println("-----------------------------------------------------------")
    getAllClassDirs().each { File file ->
        println(file.absolutePath)
    }
    println("-----------------------------------------------------------")
    getAdditionalClassDirs().each{ File file ->
        println(file.absolutePath)
    }
}

jacocoTestReport << {
    println("-----------------------------------------------------------")
    getAllClassDirs().each { File file ->
        println(file.absolutePath)
    }
    println("-----------------------------------------------------------")
    getAdditionalClassDirs().each{ File file ->
        println(file.absolutePath)
    }
}

Output
-----------------------------------------------------------
<path_here>\build\classes\main\com\bla
-----------------------------------------------------------
....more text here
-----------------------------------------------------------
<path_here>\build\classes\main\com\bla
<path_here>\build\classes\main
<path_here>\build\resources\main
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

So - the question is : is it possible to override somehow `org.gradle.testing.jacoco.plugins.JacocoPlugin#addDefaultReportTasks` method, or override completely `org.gradle.testing.jacoco.plugins.JacocoPlugin` class ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, found a workaround :

```
jacocoTestReport.doFirst{
    classDirectories = files('build/classes/main/com/bla')
}
```

This overrides classDirectories set by JacocoPlugin class.

Comment: Is this including only those `classDirectories`?

Comment: Sorry, it was long time ago, I am not up to date with the latest state of the project.

Comment: I ended up asking my own question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887805/filter-jacoco-coverage-reports-with-gradle.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a task names something other than

```
test
```

that runs unit tests, you should be able to generate the report adding the following task to your build.gradle file:

```
jacocoTestReport {
    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generates Jacoco coverage reports for unit tests"
    executionData = files('build/jacoco/unitTest.exec')
    reports {
        html.destination = 'build/reports/coverage'
    }
}
```

This needs to be called explicitly after the task to run unit tests, e.g:

```
gradle unitTest jacocoTestReport
```